# Adding an item to the list when submit jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I add an element to my list with clicking on "Add button" *without* losing style of my "li" in a new element. When I'm trying to add with append() it loses my styling. I know why it loses but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <input type="text" class="text_field" placeholder="Write a new task here..." onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write a new task here...'" />
    <input type="submit" class="add_btn" value="Add" />

    <div class="items">
        <ul class="sortable">
            <li>
                <input class='tasks' type='checkbox' />
                <p>Meet Larry at 6pm</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tasks {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    display: block;
}
.tasks:before {
    content:"";width: 19px;height: 19px;border: 1px solid #43d6b0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to update your question, use the `edit` link, don't put code in comments.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to add elements to the list.

Comment: where is your code to append an item?

Comment: `$('.add_btn').click(function(){
    $('ul').append($('<li>', {
         text: $('.text_field').val()
    }));
});` @scrappedcola

Comment: Sorry for this mess. It doesn't apply so much symbols of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="wrapper">
<form name="newItem" id="newItem">
    <input type="text" class="text_field" id="task" placeholder="Write a new task here..." onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write a new task here...'" />
    <input type="button" id="addItem" class="add_btn" value="Add" />
    </form>
    <div class="items">
        <ul id="tasks" class="sortable">
            <li>
                <input class='tasks' type='checkbox' />
                <p>Meet Larry at 6pm</p>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input class='tasks' type='checkbox' />
                <p>Ovesyan cool mandsadd</p>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input class='tasks' type='checkbox' />
                <p>dsadsa dsadasda adsdasddasdasdasda</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $("#addItem").click(function(){
        var task = $('#task').val();
        $("#tasks").append("<li><input class='tasks' type='checkbox' /><p>" + task + "</p></li>");
      });

     $("#newItem").on('submit',function(e){                 
       //add stuff to database if necessary
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
      });
</script>
```

This should do what you're looking for.  See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7ZWM/).

Edit: See final fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9NsmS/6/)

Comment: li{border-right: 6px solid;} And I made colors of the border randomly changeable. Everything is good with your answer except this. Can you please edit this too? Thanks @dcclassics

Comment: How can I store my tasks to make them not disappear after refreshing page?

Comment: You'll either have to write them to a file or a database.  That's a little bit more complicated than we can really solve here.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823535/how-to-write-data-into-a-json-file-using-jquery) to see how to write to local storage using JSON.  Else, you'll have to learn how to use a server side programming language like PHP to write files or into a database.  Someone else may have an easier solution for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7ZWM/1/ I'm not sure if this is exactly how you wanted to look?

Comment: Thanks for explanation about storin tasks!

Comment: You see, if we add a new item , it will appear without a border and checkboxes don't work in new items too

Comment: Ah yes, it's also unclickable.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about:)

Comment: So the reason it's happening, is because the style is being applied to all of the items on page load, and then it's not being applied again once you add new items. A very incorrect but working solution is to just apply them again when you add an item:  http://jsfiddle.net/9NsmS/6/