# How can I store and get data from json file?

Tags: html, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have create html template based on bootstrap I need to store and get data from registration forms using j-son file.

I do not know how I can set and get data to json file. How can I do this?

```js
$(function () {
    $('.button-checkbox').each(function () {

        // Settings
        var $widget = $(this),
            $button = $widget.find('button'),
            $checkbox = $widget.find('input:checkbox'),
            color = $button.data('color'),
            settings = {
                on: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check'
                },
                off: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked'
                }
            };

        // Event Handlers
        $button.on('click', function () {
            $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
            $checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
            updateDisplay();
        });
        $checkbox.on('change', function () {
            updateDisplay();
        });

        // Actions
        function updateDisplay() {
            var isChecked = $checkbox.is(':checked');

            // Set the button's state
            $button.data('state', (isChecked) ? "on" : "off");

            // Set the button's icon
            $button.find('.state-icon')
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon);

            // Update the button's color
            if (isChecked) {
                $button
                    .removeClass('btn-default')
                    .addClass('btn-' + color + ' active');
            }
            else {
                $button
                    .removeClass('btn-' + color + ' active')
                    .addClass('btn-default');
            }
        }

        // Initialization
        function init() {

            updateDisplay();

            // Inject the icon if applicable
            if ($button.find('.state-icon').length == 0) {
                $button.prepend('<i class="state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon + '"></i>');
            }
        }
        init();
    });
});
```

```css
/* Credit to bootsnipp.com for the css for the color graph */
.colorgraph {
  height: 5px;
  border-top: 0;
  background: #c4e17f;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #c4e17f, #c4e17f 12.5%, #f7fdca 12.5%, #f7fdca 25%, #fecf71 25%, #fecf71 37.5%, #f0776c 37.5%, #f0776c 50%, #db9dbe 50%, #db9dbe 62.5%, #c49cde 62.5%, #c49cde 75%, #669ae1 75%, #669ae1 87.5%, #62c2e4 87.5%, #62c2e4);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #c4e17f, #c4e17f 12.5%, #f7fdca 12.5%, #f7fdca 25%, #fecf71 25%, #fecf71 37.5%, #f0776c 37.5%, #f0776c 50%, #db9dbe 50%, #db9dbe 62.5%, #c49cde 62.5%, #c49cde 75%, #669ae1 75%, #669ae1 87.5%, #62c2e4 87.5%, #62c2e4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #c4e17f, #c4e17f 12.5%, #f7fdca 12.5%, #f7fdca 25%, #fecf71 25%, #fecf71 37.5%, #f0776c 37.5%, #f0776c 50%, #db9dbe 50%, #db9dbe 62.5%, #c49cde 62.5%, #c49cde 75%, #669ae1 75%, #669ae1 87.5%, #62c2e4 87.5%, #62c2e4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #c4e17f, #c4e17f 12.5%, #f7fdca 12.5%, #f7fdca 25%, #fecf71 25%, #fecf71 37.5%, #f0776c 37.5%, #f0776c 50%, #db9dbe 50%, #db9dbe 62.5%, #c49cde 62.5%, #c49cde 75%, #669ae1 75%, #669ae1 87.5%, #62c2e4 87.5%, #62c2e4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
  <form role="form">
   <h2>Please Sign Up <small>It's free and always will be.</small></h2>
   <hr class="colorgraph">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="2">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="display_name" id="display_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Display Name" tabindex="3">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="4">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="5">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="6">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
     <span class="button-checkbox">
      <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="info" tabindex="7">I Agree</button>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="t_and_c" id="t_and_c" class="hidden" value="1">
     </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
      By clicking <strong class="label label-primary">Register</strong>, you agree to the <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t_and_c_m">Terms and Conditions</a> set out by this site, including our Cookie Use.
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <hr class="colorgraph">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="7"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Sign In</a></div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="t_and_c_m" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Terms & Conditions</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, itaque, modi, aliquam nostrum at sapiente consequuntur natus odio reiciendis perferendis rem nisi tempore possimus ipsa porro delectus quidem dolorem ad.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, itaque, modi, aliquam nostrum at sapiente consequuntur natus odio reiciendis perferendis rem nisi tempore possimus ipsa porro delectus quidem dolorem ad.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, itaque, modi, aliquam nostrum at sapiente consequuntur natus odio reiciendis perferendis rem nisi tempore possimus ipsa porro delectus quidem dolorem ad.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, itaque, modi, aliquam nostrum at sapiente consequuntur natus odio reiciendis perferendis rem nisi tempore possimus ipsa porro delectus quidem dolorem ad.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, itaque, modi, aliquam nostrum at sapiente consequuntur natus odio reiciendis perferendis rem nisi tempore possimus ipsa porro delectus quidem dolorem ad.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, itaque, modi, aliquam nostrum at sapiente consequuntur natus odio reiciendis perferendis rem nisi tempore possimus ipsa porro delectus quidem dolorem ad.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, itaque, modi, aliquam nostrum at sapiente consequuntur natus odio reiciendis perferendis rem nisi tempore possimus ipsa porro delectus quidem dolorem ad.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">I Agree</button>
   </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
 </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to be talking about something server-related but just attach CSS/HTML/JS. Where do you want your JSON to be sent?

Comment: just i need to know how i can create json file to recive data from this form and store it to use it later

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823535/how-to-write-data-into-a-json-file-using-jquery