# create .json file on run time in javascript and save it in the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, contextmenu

**This is my script. It is doing 2 things.**

- on mouse up it highlights the text
- on highlight text, when it is clicked, it opens up a context Menu

**What I want to do next is:**

- take the highlighted text as `key`
- take the selected option from context Menu as `value`
- save `key:value` pairs in `JSON` format
- write `JSON` to file

I am new to web, need suggestions on how to do it. so far , my menu items are clickable but what to do next and how to implement what i want to implement is the question i want help with.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="context_menu.js"></script>


  <style type="text/css">
    .red {
      color: red;
    }
    
    ;
    body {
      font-family: "Roboto", san-serif;
    }
    
    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .menu {
      width: 120px;
      z-index: 1;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      position: fixed;
      display: none;
      transition: 0.2s display ease-in;
      .menu-options {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 10px 0;
        z-index: 1;
        .menu-option {
          font-weight: 500;
          z-index: 1;
          font-size: 14px;
          padding: 10px 40px 10px 20px;
          // border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          cursor: pointer;
          &:hover {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    button {
      background: grey;
      border: none;
      .next {
        color: green;
      }
      &[disabled="false"]:hover {
        .next {
          color: red;
          animation: move 0.5s;
          animation-iteration-count: 2;
        }
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes move {
      from {
        transform: translate(0%);
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-40%);
      }
      to {
        transform: transform(0%);
      }
    }
  </style>

  <body>


    <div class="menu">
      <ul class="menu-options">
        <li class="menu-option" id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Animal</li>
        <li class="menu-option">Bird</li>
        <li class="menu-option">Human</li>
        <li class="menu-option">Alien</li>
        <li class="menu-option">No one</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="select--highlight--active">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset imply dummy text sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
      recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

  </body>
  <script>
    const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
    console.log(menu)
    let menuVisible = false;
    const toggleMenu = command => {
      console.log("Togel : " + command)
      menu.style.display = command === "show" ? "block" : "none";
      menuVisible = !menuVisible;
    };

    const setPosition = ({
      top,
      left
    }) => {
      console.log(top)
      console.log(left)
      menu.style.left = `${left}px`;
      menu.style.top = `${top}px`;
      toggleMenu("show");
    };

    // window.addEventListener("click", e => {
    //    
    // });

    $(function() {
      thisRespondHightlightText(".select--highlight--active");
    });
    /*thisRespondHightlightText(".select--highlight--active");*/


    function thisRespondHightlightText(thisDiv) {
      $(thisDiv).on("mouseup", function() {
        console.log("EVENT")
        var selectedText = getSelectionText();
        var selectedTextRegExp = new RegExp(selectedText, "g");
        var text = $(this).text().replace(selectedTextRegExp, "<span class='red'>" + selectedText + "</span>");
        console.log("Text " + selectedText)
        $(this).html(text);
        if (selectedText == "") {
          toggleMenu("hide");
        } else {

          const origin = {
            left: 100,
            top: 100
          };
          setPosition(origin);
        }

      });
    }

    function getSelectionText() {
      var text = "";
      if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
      } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        alert("In else")
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
      }

      return text;
    }

    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "I am an Animal!";
    }
  </script>
</head>



</html>
```

Comment: You cannot create a file using Javascript on the client side.

Comment: You should save data into localStorage instead.. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20823621/7035903

Comment: *my menu items are clickable* ... no **one** element is clickable

Comment: This code is a total mess. I have no idea what your trying to do but I'm sure this isn't  remotely doing it. VTC too broad

Comment: @Liam sorry yes one is clickable, its there just to explain what i have done and what i am trying to do next

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava but i can crate JSON right ? so if you could help me in creating part ?

Comment: @shreyasdharav yes i have already seen it, but i dont want to use local storage. will see about storage part of it. for now if someone could help me in creating JSON that would be great

Comment: you can't  to write on json file at client side

Comment: @AjayPandya can I create something in a form of `key:value` pair ?

Comment: Try creating json data like `var jsonData = {};` then add items like `jsonData[key] = value;`. Just apply the code correctly where you need it.

Comment: @Dumisani let me try it as well, will get back to you

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is just not a good fit for SO. SO questions should be reasonably scoped and require a definitive answer. This code is a long way form what you want. Maybe try and break the problem down into smaller pieces. I'd advise you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands I'd expect this question to (eventually) get closed as [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Dumisani it is working. If you can add it as answer i can accept it

Comment: @irumzahra Glad it helped. Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create JSON data declare it using

```
var jsonData = {};
```

Then assign `key:value` items to it

```
jsonData[key] = value;
```

You can later access its data by using the keys

```
var value = jsonData.key;
var value = jsonData['key'];
```